# How to override dependency on certain task in sbt

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I want to override dependency on project in certain Task.
I have a sbt multi-project which using spark.

```
lazy val core = // Some Project

val sparkLibs = Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.1"
)

val sparkLibsProvided = Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.1" % "provided"
)

lazy val main = Project(
  id = "main",
  base = file("main-project"),
  settings = sharedSettings
).settings(
  name := "main",
  libraryDependencies ++= sparkLibs,
  dependencyOverrides ++= Set(
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.4.4"
  )
).dependsOn(core)
```

When I try to make fat jar to submit on my yarn cluster, I use https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly task. But in this case, I want to use `sparkLibsProvided` instead of `sparkLibs` something like:

```
lazy val sparkProvided = (project in assembly).settings(
  dependencyOverrides ++= sparkLibsProvided.toSet
)
```

How can I properly override this dependency?

Comment: why can't you mark this dependency as `provided` for all scopes?

Comment: @Sergey I want to test it locally, so I need the dependencies without `provided`. I could delete `provieded` while test my project locally but, you know, I'm lazy

Comment: As far as I know, ´provided´ scope is made specifically to be available in ´compile´ and ´test´ scopes. In case you want to test it locally by running a main class rather than in tests, well, you can provide the dependency manually :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new project which is a dedicated project for creating your spark uber jar with the provided flag:

```
lazy val sparkUberJar = (project in file("spark-project"))
  .settings(sharedSettings: _*)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= sparkLibsProvided,
    dependencyOverrides ++= Set(
      "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.4.4"
    )
  )
```

And when you assemble in sbt, go to the said project first:

```
sbt project sparkUberJar
sbt assembly
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved by using the [key](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#assemblyexcludedjars) provided specifically for what you want:

```
assemblyExcludedJars in assembly := { 
  val cp = (fullClasspath in assembly).value
  cp filter {
    _.data.getName == "spark-core-1.6.1.jar"
  }
}
```

This approach is considered hacky, however, and it would be better if you managed to split your configuration into subprojects, as is also warned in official documentation [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#excluding-jars-and-files):

> If you need to tell sbt-assembly to ignore JARs, you're probably doing it wrong. assembly task grabs deps JARs from your project's classpath. Try fixing the classpath first.